# HTTP401 when trying to query WSUS server

Tags: windows, powershell, windows-server-2012-r2

```
[void][reflection.assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("Microsoft.UpdateServices.Administration")
$wsus = [Microsoft.UpdateServices.Administration.AdminProxy]::getUpdateServer($WSUS_Server,$false,80)
```

> The request failed  with HTTP status 401: Unauthorized.

Both machines are in same work-group and I've set the registry value to `Unrestricted`:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\PowerShell\1\ShellIds\ScriptedDiagnostics\ExecutionPolicy
```

Why am I getting a 401 error?

Comment: Apparently, your account doesn't have access to the server.

Comment: When I run the command by directly invoking a powershell prompt it works, but when I invoke the same command through 'EXEC' call it does not.

Comment: I've run in SYSTEM user context, still it's 401 !@TheIncorrigible1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to provide credentials of target machine.

You can use powershell commandlets to achieve this

$cred = get-credential

OR

$password = ConvertTo-SecureString "PlainTextPassword" -AsPlainText -Force
$cred= New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential ("username", $password )